# ActiveMQ 5.5: Not able to get the DLQ_DELIVERY_FAILURE_CAUSE_PROPERTY value

Tags: activemq-classic

I am not able to get the reason of exception from the message that is in the DLQ.
These are the steps i have followed:-

1. Message is sent to a 'Sample' Queue.
2. The Message Listener throws a Runtime Exception in the onMessage Function.(throw new RuntimeException("Exception Reason Test");)
3. The message goes to the DLQ.
4. I am trying to access the Exception reason via two approaches(i pass the DLQ Name and the JMS Message ID in both):-

   - Spring JMSTemplate browseSelected function

(ActiveMQMessage)message.getStringProperty(ActiveMQMessage.DLQ_DELIVERY_FAILURE_CAUSE_PROPERTY);

- JMX QueueViewMBean browse function via the composite data map

Map datamap =  (Map)dataMap.get("StringProperties");

datamap.containsKey(ActiveMQMessage.DLQ_DELIVERY_FAILURE_CAUSE_PROPERTY);

In both cases i am getting a null value for the property DLQ_DELIVERY_FAILURE_CAUSE_PROPERTY.

Please help.
Thanks